# Ansible Tower server claims it was sent a bad request

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have written a playbook to create credentials with custom credentials, below is the ansible playbook

```
---
- name: Trigger an Atower API
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Create a valid SCM credential from a private_key file
      command: tower-cli credential create --organization "Default" --name "DevOps User" --credential-type "csa-test2" --inputs "{'user':'devops', 'stg01_ssh_key':\"$( sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' test.pem )\" }"
      no_log: false
```

I am getting this error related to quotaions

```
name", "DevOps User", "--credential-type", "csa-test2", "--inputs", "{'user':'devops', 'stg01_ssh_key':\"$( sed -z 's/\\n/\\n/g' test.pem )\" }"], "delta": "0:00:01.319114", "end": "2021-01-07 16:00:22.763388", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 40, "start": "2021-01-07 16:00:21.444274", "stderr": "Error: The Tower server claims it was sent a bad request.\n\nPOST http://x.x.x.x:13080/api/v2/credentials/\nParams: None\nData: {\"inputs\": {\"stg01_ssh_key\": \"$( sed -z 's/\\n/\\n/g' test.pem )\", \"user\": \"devops\"}, \"credential_type\": 36, \"organization\": 1, \"name\": \"DevOps User\"}\n\nResponse: {\"inputs\":{\"stg01_ssh_key\":[\"Invalid certificate or key: $( sed -z 's/\\n/\\n/g' test.pem )...\"]}}", "stderr_lines": ["Error: The Tower server claims it was sent a bad request.", "", "POST http://x.x.x.x:13080/api/v2/credentials/", "Params: None", "Data: {\"inputs\": {\"stg01_ssh_key\": \"$( sed -z 's/\\n/\\n/g' test.pem )\", \"user\": \"devops\"}, \"credential_type\": 36, \"organization\": 1, \"name\": \"DevOps User\"}", "", "Response: {\"inputs\":{\"stg01_ssh_key\":[\"Invalid certificate or key: $( sed -z 's/\\n/\\n/g' test.pem )...\"]}}"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Also, when i try manually "tower-cli create" command, it is working fine. Can anyone help me in this. I dunno what is wrong here.

Comment: try to use shell instead of command, documentation says:

The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOSTNAME and operations like "*", "<", ">", "|", ";" and "&" will not work. Use the ansible.builtin.shell module if you need these features.

Comment: Thanks @CyrilleMODIANO. You are right. I changed to shell command. It Worked!!

Comment: @Mathan The SO way to say thank you is to accept the correct answer (green tick). This is also a way to let other know there is a working solution. You can also upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use shell instead of command, documentation says

The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like `$HOSTNAME` and operations like `"*", "<", ">", "|", ";"` and `"&"` will not work. Use the ansible.builtin.shell module if you need these features.

source: [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html)